# How can I use SwiftUI to populate content in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: uicollectionview, swiftui, uicollectionviewcell

Because `SwiftUI` has no `UICollectionView-like` controls,so  I used `UIKit` instead.

According to [interfacing-with-uikit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit), I know how `SwiftUI` interacts with `UIKit`, but I want to further use `SwiftUI` to encapsulate `UICollectionViewCell`, and use `SwiftUI` to fill the content of `UICollectionViewCell`, how can I do that.

As far as I know List in `SwiftUI` are encapsulated according to `UITableView`, I want `SwiftUI` to do the same with `UICollectionView`,I don't want to use some tripartite libraries to do this, I want to learn the secrets

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `CellContentView` SwiftUI view, you can integrate it in `UICollectionViewCell` using something like the following

```
if let cellContent = UIHostingController(rootView: CellContentView()).view {
    cell.contentView.addSubview(cellContent)

    cellContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellContent.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    cellContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    cellContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works fine, except I'm unable to interact with the SwiftUI view.  I can't press a Button in my SwiftUI view, so I tried adding a List and I'm unable to scroll the List either.  Perhaps a layering issue?