# SwiftUI View in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and I'm trying to design my UICollectionViewCell's using SwiftUI. I've seen two examples, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909633/how-can-i-use-swiftui-to-populate-content-in-a-uicollectionviewcell/60910075#comment114687057_60910075) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902805/using-swiftui-views-for-uicollectionviewcell-inside-a-uiviewrepresentable-collec/61916422#comment114660871_61916422) that have done this in the following manner in their UICollectionViewCell:

```swift
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeSwiftUIView)
let view = controller.view!
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(view)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

This works fine visually, but a problem I'm having is I do not have user interaction with the SwiftUI view.  For example, if I have a Button in the SwiftUI view, the action is not performed when you tap the button.  If a List is in the SwiftUI view, you cannot scroll this view. (I'm not trying to put a List in it, this is just an example)

Any recommendations on where to go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by constraining the view to the cell rather than the contentView, and it is working fine now.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
])
```

As I suspected, this was a layering issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the view to the cell directly and setting the constraints on the contentView.

When you add the view to the content view it will work as expected, so looking at your code if we only have to change the 4th line to `contentView.addSubview(view)` like so it would become:

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeSwiftUIView)
let view = controller.view!
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(view)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Apple also suggests to add the content of a cell into the content view and not directly into the view of the cell. [See docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview)